# Pygame sideways scrolling: platforms continue moving in opposite direction towards position 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I fail at implementing a functioning sideways scrolling for a platformer using pygame: Whenever the player is not centered horizontally, I want the world (i.e. platforms) to scroll.

I believe the relevant code part in the main loop is:

```
if self.player.rect.center[0] != WIDTH/2:
    self.player.pos.x -= self.player.vel.x
    for pl in self.platforms:
        pl.rect.x -= self.player.vel.x
```

However, what happens is that

- when player moves to left, all platforms with x position < 0 move at a constant speed to the right but only until x = 0;
- when player moves to right, all platforms with x position > 0 move at a constant speed to the left but only until x = 0.

Sometimes the platforms do not move all the way until x = 0. I believe they stop when the player velocity is practically 0.

[image: Hopefully this makes it more clear. The platforms should not move relative to each other. (Sorry about the artifacts)]

What did I miss? I really can't see why the platforms behave so weirdly.

Comment: problem has to be in different part of code - so we can't help without rest of code.

Comment: BTW: instead of `center[0]` you can use `centerx`

Comment: Sorry, but we can't help you unless you contribute all of your code.  We need to know how the different pieces interact with each other to find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the reason for this is that you used the (+= velocity) method on both the self.player.pos.x and p1.rect.x. This causes multiple problems as the player is only able to move when its not in the center(meaning once its in the center it isn't getting out), and that the platforms are moving at the same speed and in the same direction as the player should be. This is what is causing those weird effects. (you need to divide the vel in half btw otherwise you will move twice as fast!!!)

```
self.player.pos.x -= self.player.vel.x/2
if self.player.rect.center[0] != WIDTH/2:
    for plat in self.platforms:
        plat.rect.x += self.player.vel.x/2
```